# Output number from c++ as bytes and read it in python

Tags: python, c++

Lets say I have some integer in c++ code. I want to send this integer to python as bytes. The next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream output;
    uint32_t schemaHash = 3049619955;
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&schemaHash), sizeof(schemaHash));
    std::cout << output.str() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

outputs єБ┼╡.

Then I copy these bytes and try to parse them in the following way:

```
import struct

data = input().encode()
print(struct.unpack_from("=I", data))
```

This code outputs (2446365905,).

The question is how to fix this. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong and how to interpret c++ integer as bytes in python.

Comment: What do you mean "copy these bytes"? A literal copy and paste will have all kinds of funky behavior depending on the OS you're on, where you're copying/pasting to etc etc...

Comment: First, you should not use `std::string` for raw data.  If you really want to write binary to `std::cout`, then reopen the stream in binary mode and use `std::cout.write`.  This will only be useful if you're doing it on the same machine, where you can guarantee architecture, both regarding integer size and endianness.  It's very puzzling why you are writing a `\n` after this data.

Comment: Looking at the Python docs for `struct.unpack_from`, it appears you might also need to specify `"=I"`, otherwise the size could possibly be interpreted as "native" instead of "standard".

Comment: Adding =I and writing in binary mode seems to still not working. New c++ code https://ideone.com/d3bn90. Python code remains unchanged. Python output changed to 2211480529.

Comment: I managed to do this. Thank you for your answers!